# Transit visa required in Paris, France?

Tags: schengen, transit, israel, filipino-citizens, abu-dhabi

I'm flying from Singapore to Tel Aviv, Israel and will be transiting in Paris, France for about 2.5 hours via Air France. Do I need to apply transit visa?

Going back time is from Israel to Rome, Italy to Abu Dabhi and Singapore. Do I need to apply visa entering Rome and Abu Dhabi?

By the way, I'm working in Singapore and holding a Philippine passport.

Comment: That's one hell of a strange route! Direct it would be just under 5000 miles, but the way you're doing it is almost 9000!

Answer (score 0):

Taking it one step at a time:

1. Singapore to Tel Aviv, transiting in France.

If you are staying in the international transit area at the airport in France, you do not need a visa.

2. Tel Aviv to Singapore, transit through Rome, and then Abu Dhabi

If you are staying in the international transit area in Rome, you do not need a transit visa. For Abu Dhabi you do not need a transit visa.

You can find out more information on transit visa requirements at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit).